# Create pipeline run in data factory v2 using rest api

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am using nodeJS to create a pipelin run in data factory v2 and i need to pass two parameters in the body. While doing this the parameters are not passed to the pipeline. The pipeline  is been triggered but the parameters i am passing in JSO format are not taken by the pipeline

Creating options constant that I use in my request:

```
    const options = {
            hostname: 'management.azure.com',
            port: 443,
            path: '/subscriptions/<subscriptionId>/resourceGroups/<resourceGroup>/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/<datafactoryName>/pipelines/<pipelineName>/createRun?api-version=2018-06-01',
            method: 'POST',
            body: req.body,
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer <token>',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        };
```

The req.body looks like this:

```
   {
     “inputpath”: “input file location”,
     “outputpath”: “output file location”
   }
```

The final request to ADFv2 Rest API:

```
 var req = https.request(options, result => {
            result.on('data', (chunk) => {
                res.send(chunk);
            });
        })
        req.on('data', (data) => {
        });
```

Comment: Please provide detailed nodejs code which run your pipeline and pass parameters.

Comment: @JayGong Added the code samples

Comment: How did you find the parameters are not taken? Is your pipeline payload correct? Have you tried trigger it in UI?

Comment: @FangLiu: I checked it in ADF pipeline runs. When I trigger the pipeline from the UI with parameters then the pipeline works just fine.

Comment: You could press F12 to open the browser debug mode and then go to the network tab. You will find what is the payload UI send out when your click trigger now button. Hope you could help you to check the api payload.